# android studio missing class wizard

Tags: java, android-studio

I just updated android studio to version 4.0.1, and when I try to create a new java class, the class wizard won't appear anymore. the only option available is to choose the class name and that's it.

What I expected to see:
[class wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tsrV.png) (image from android studio documentation)

what I actually got:
[the menu selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3lVI.png),
[the new "wizard"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5rh5.png)

This generates a completely empty class. The old wizard let me choose
the super class, generate the onCreate() method for me and import the relevant stuff.

Am I just missing the correct menu option or is something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem bro..I also want that wizard to select superclass

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, google intentionally change the previous Class creation Dialog. So there is no way to bring the previous "**Create New Class**" Dialog.

Found an issue regarding this.

**Android Studio 4.0 Create New Class dialog missing/very different since upgrading.**

Google Replied as below:

```
I'm sorry
We intentionally went back closer to upstream IntelliJ IDEA with the New - Java Class behavior. That old dialog is not coming back.
```

Issue Link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157968677?pli=1